# Getting columns to fill just a certain percentage of the screen

Tags: html, css, vue.js, quasar-framework

**Problem**

I have a layout where the idea is there are 2 columns, side by side, as shown in this screenshot, but to not have the columns go past the q-footer:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJlhL.png)

Regardless of the amount of content in each div (column), I'd like for both divs to never go below the q-footer (i.e. always be a fixed percentage of the height of the page or stick to the top of the q-footer) so the user doesn't have to scroll the actual page.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried doing things like setting the style="min-height: 80%; max-height: 80%" on the divs, but had no luck, or at least if it did work, content would bleed outside of the div, so the page still would have to be scrolled if either list got too long.

**Code**

Here is my code so far: (Using the Quasar library for the front-end UI)

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex row">

    <!-- Chat Window -->
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <ChatView />
    </div>

    <!-- User List -->
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <ChatUserList />
    </div>

    <!-- Chat Message Input -->
    <q-footer elevated>
      <q-toolbar>
        <q-input outlined rounded v-model="newMessage" class="full-width" label="Message" dense bg-color="white">
          <template v-slot:after>
            <q-btn round dense flat icon="send" color="white" />
          </template>
        </q-input>
      </q-toolbar>

    </q-footer>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

Comment: Please create a reproducible demo using this: https://codesandbox.io/s/